# Multidimensional Json to String Using PHP

Tags: php, json

I just playing around with coding for couple month and don't know how to solved this problem, ok here is the problem

I got this type of json

```
{
"PC": {
    "Acer": {
        "Series 1" : "Series 1",
        "Series 2" : "Series 2",
        "Series 3" : "Series 3",
    },
    "Lenovo": {
        "Series 1" : "Series 1",
        "Series 2" : "Series 2",
        "Series 3" : "Series 3",
    }
},
"Apple": {
    "Macbook": {
        "Series 1" : "Series 1",
        "Series 2" : "Series 2",
        "Series 3" : "Series 3",
    }
    "Iphone": {
        "Series 1" : "Series 1",
        "Series 2" : "Series 2",
        "Series 3" : "Series 3",
    }
},
}
```

My question how to make this multi dimensional json into something like this

```
PC, Acer, Series 1
PC, Acer, Series 2
PC, Acer, Series 3
PC, Lenovo, Series 1
PC, Lenovo, Series 2
PC, Lenovo, Series 3
Apple, Macbook, Series 1
Apple, Macbook, Series 2
Apple, Macbook, Series 3
Apple, Iphone, Series 1
Apple, Iphone, Series 2
Apple, Iphone, Series 3
```

Should I use multi foreach? or is there any other way who not consume to many memory?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try to find some solution to convert JSON as regex. Also you can play with options when the structure is different or not defined at all. Then you need some smart solution with recursion.

This is a simple solution when you know your structure and using PHP json decoder and foreach loops.

First of all you have to fix your json, it has errors and won't be processed by PHP decoder:

```
$json = "{
\"PC\": {
    \"Acer\": {
        \"Series 1\" : \"Series 1\",
        \"Series 2\" : \"Series 2\",
        \"Series 3\" : \"Series 3\"
    },
    \"Lenovo\": {
        \"Series 1\" : \"Series 1\",
        \"Series 2\" : \"Series 2\",
        \"Series 3\" : \"Series 3\"
    }
},
\"Apple\": {
    \"Macbook\": {
        \"Series 1\" : \"Series 1\",
        \"Series 2\" : \"Series 2\",
        \"Series 3\" : \"Series 3\"
    },
    \"Iphone\": {
        \"Series 1\" : \"Series 1\",
        \"Series 2\" : \"Series 2\",
        \"Series 3\" : \"Series 3\"
    }
}
}";
```

Now you can run the solution with the format and expected result given:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($data as $system => $brand) {
    foreach($brand as $name => $series) {
        foreach($series as $val) {
            echo "$system, $name, $val\n";
        }
    }
}
```